# How to handle apostrophes in Android localization files?

Tags: android, ios, localization, localio

I'm using [Localio](https://github.com/mrmans0n/localio) to extract translations for my IOS and Android apps.

With IOS, I don't have an issue. But Android doesn't let me to use apostrophes without escaping. But Localio code doesn't do that. For example:

```
    <string name="account_suspended_message">Ce compte a été suspendu. S'il vous plaît contacter l'administrateur.</string>
```

It is giving

```
Apostrophe not preceded by \
```

error.

How can I avoid these kind of errors? Should I write a script for that?

Comment: The answer is within your question. Just precede your apostrophe by /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, you must precede all apostrophe with \ like follows

```
<string name="account_suspended_message">Ce compte a été suspendu. S\'il vous plaît contacter l\'administrateur.</string>
```

You can write manually or with a script, as you want

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the Translator Editor of Android Studio, it will manage those things for you.

When you open your strings.xml, above there is a bar that sats Open in Editor.

There is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the straight (ASCII) apostrophe in translations - use the typographic apostrophe ’ instead. The Unicode character code is U+2019, and according to http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf this is the preferred character to use for apostrophe, and it works for both Android and iOS.

If you absolutely have to use the single straight quote as an apostrophe you have to escape it by prefixing it with a backslash. Using `&apos;`, as one might expect in XML, is not supported by Android.